# WinSCP.com: how to skip the password prompt in the script if key authentication fails

Tags: shell, command-line, command-line-interface, winscp

I'm using WinSCP CLI to script a file transfer. I'm using the private/public key authentication only, the password is not set.

```
WinSCP.com /nointeractiveinput 
           /command "open sftp://USER@HOST/ -privatekey=PATH_TO_KEY ..." 
           ...
```

I am testing error situations now. One error situation is that key authentication can fail. In this case the password prompt is presented and the script blocks. Calling `/nointeractiveinput ...` doesn't help, since it will not skip the password prompt.

**Question**: What can I do to skip the password promt and let the script fail if key authentication doesn'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/nointeractiveinput` switch should actually help in this scenario.

Make sure you are using the latest version of WinSCP.

Comment: Updating to the newest version helped. Now it works as expected. The older version (4.x) that I used didn't complain about the switch so I was assuming it was a valid one.